# How to get the psql table records in shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, array

I have postgresql, in that I have a table with  10 records, I want the 10 records in 10 local variables shell script.

I tried with following way, but it will store all the records in list123[0] variable not on list123[1]...list123[9].

```
declare -a list123
list123=( "$(psql -t -h 10.100.0.1 -U prasad statistics -c "select command from jobhandler.config_info where conf_name like '%stager%'")" )
```

I want each record in corresponding list123[0-9].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I'm answering your question. Do you want an array of 10 strings as a local variable, or 10 shell variables, each containing a string?

The latter requires a weird trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=1
eval $(psql -t -h 10.100.0.1 -U prasad statistics -c "select command from jobhandler.config_info where conf_name like '%stager%'" |
while read VAR
do
    echo "list123$COUNTER='$VAR'"
    ((COUNTER = COUNTER + 1))
done)

echo list1231="$list1231"
echo list1232="$list1232"
```

This variant ends up setting shell variables named "list1231", "list1232", "list1233" ..., it does not set different elements of an array shell variable named "list123"

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the double-quotes you've placed around the `$()` command substitution.  That turns the entire output into a single multi-line string.

Try:

```
declare -a list123
list123=( $(psql -t -h 10.100.0.1 -U prasad statistics -c "select command from jobhandler.config_info where conf_name like '%stager%'") )
```

I don't have your table, but i tested with a simple id,name,dob table on my system:

```
$ list123=($(psql -t -c 'select dob from newtable'))
$ set | grep list123
list123=([0]="1967-03-07" [1]="1964-08-07" [2]="1992-10-19" [3]="1964-12-18" [4]="1945-12-26")
```